# How to correctly use enumerate with two inputs and three expected outputs in python spark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, lambda, pyspark, enumerate

I've been tryng to replicate the code in http://www.data-intuitive.com/2015/01/transposing-a-spark-rdd/ to traspose an RDD in pyspark. I am able to load my RDD correctly and apply the zipWithIndex method to it as follows:

```
m1.rdd.zipWithIndex().collect()
[(Row(c1_1=1, c1_2=2, c1_3=3), 0),
(Row(c1_1=4, c1_2=5, c1_3=6), 1),
(Row(c1_1=7, c1_2=8, c1_3=9), 2)]
```

But, when I want to apply it a flatMap with a lambda enumerating that array either the syntax is non-valid:

```
m1.rdd.zipWithIndex().flatMap(lambda (x,i): [(i,j,e) for (j,e) in enumerate(x)]).take(1)
```

Or, the positional argument i appears as missing:

```
m1.rdd.zipWithIndex().flatMap(lambda x,i: [(i,j,e) for (j,e) in enumerate(x)]).take(1)
```

When I run the lambda in python, it needs an extra index parameter to catch the function.

```
aa = m1.rdd.zipWithIndex().collect()
g = lambda x,i: [(i,j,e) for (j,e) in enumerate(x)]
g(aa,3) #extra parameter
```

Which seems to me unnecessary as the index has been calculated previously.

I'm quite an amateur in python and spark and I would like to know what is the issue with the indexes and why neither spark nor python are catching them. Thank you.

Comment: If your final aim is to transpose the rdd, convert to block matrix, transpose it and get it back to rdd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's take a look a the signature of `RDD.flatMap` (`preservesPartitioning` parameter removed for clarity):

```
flatMap(self: RDD[T], f: Callable[[T], Iterable[U]]) -> RDD[U]: ...
```

As you can see `flatMap` expects an [**unary** function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_function).

Going back to your code:

- `lambda x, i: ...` is a [binary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_function), so clearly it won't work.
- `lambda (x, i): ...` use to be a syntax for an unary function with [tuple argument unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/). It used structural matching to destructure (unpack in Python nomenclature) a single input argument (here `Tuple[Any, Any]`). This syntax was brittle and has been removed in Python 3. A correct way to achieve the same result in Python 3 is indexing:

  ```
  lambda xi: ((x[1], j, e) for e, j in enumerate(x[0]))
  ```

  If you prefer structural matching just use standard function:

  ```
  def flatten(xsi):
      xs, i = xsi
      for j, x in enumerate(xs):
          yield i, j, x

  rdd.flatMap(flatten)
  ```